# How to run yii2 cronjob from linux

Tags: php, cron, yii2

I created a `cronjob` controller in `yii2project/console/controllers` :

```
namespace console\controllers;

use yii\base\Model;

use yii\console\Controller;

use Yii;

class MycronController extends Controller {

    public function actionIndex() {

        echo "cron service runnning";
        die;
    }

}
```

In windows i am running this file :

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2project>d:\xampp\php\php yii mycron
```

output:

```
cron service running
```

Now how to run this in linux?

Comment: If php is available in a folder of your ``$PATH`` variable you can just run  ``php /path/to/my/script.php"``

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions worked for me, atleast. To make it work from `crontab`, you have to provide the following command:

```
* * * * *  php /path/to/project/root/yii controller-name/action-name
```

This example will run every minute by the way. For more information about cronjobs, check [this link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800) out.

By the way, if you just want to run the job from your SSH terminal, use this one instead:

```
php /path/to/project/root/yii controller-name/action-name
```

Edit: Make sure you have run init command after installing yii with composer. That sets the necessary permissions to run the yii script. If you still can't run it, try `chmod +x yii` to make the script executable.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:
(take the $ symbol off)

```
$ /xampp/php/php/./yii mycron
```

Answer (score 0):

```
php yii mycron
```

run in `yii2project` folder

Comment: when you posting the answer please give the proper explanation..So that guys who are looking the answer can get easily..

Answer (score 0):

The Cron-Job is for CentOs.
Open the terminal and navigate to your project folder

> cd /var/www/html/advancedyii2

After entering into the folder type

> crontab -e

The cron-manager file will be opened in the terminal.

Now edit the cron file like

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/advancedyii2/yii controller/function
```

Before executing the above command make sure a controller is created under

> /var/www/html/advancedyii2/console 
>        - Here create a controller and function to server your need

For more about Cron-Configurations [Visit this link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800)